# Im looking to add cyclic lines in pinescript, but I could not seem to find any api inside of pinescript to do so

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

So basically my goal, is to have multiple cyclic lines starting at a start date I chose in the code along with the width of the lines. I was wondering if there was a way to do it.

I tried to add vertical lines but that would not work if I am adding multiple cyclic lines.

Comment: What is a cyclic line ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.